# Can I set font-size accordingly to font availability?

Tags: css, font-size

Is it possible to set a different font-size according to font availability?

Currently my problem is that `Verdana` is too big, and if the user don't have `Verdana` installed, I will end up with a very small font-size

Is there is any way to set a font (`Verdana` in my case) to 13px and if the user don't have that font installed, try with another font (`Arial` for example) but with bigger font-size?

**Notes:**

- Preferably CSS only
- CSS hacks allowed

Comment: The question is, are there computers out there that have Arial, but not Verdana. According to [this](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResultsFull.shtml), that scenario is unlikely.

Comment: I'm with @ŠimeVidas - I wouldn't worry too much about people not having Verdana - those cases will be **very** rare.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I understand this scenario is unlikely, but what if someone else want to do this with other fonts that are likely to don't be installed by default?

Comment: @ajax333221 Consider rephrasing the question, so that it becomes more general. For instance, the title could be "How to detect font availability and set the font-size accordingly?"...

Comment: @Xeoncross So, you're the one.. `:P`

Comment: There is no CSS only solution.

Comment: @thirtydot, what should one do with bounty on unanswerable questions? (this is my first bounty, Idk what to do, help)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work. You might also just want to search for a JavaScript solution to this problem (I'm sure one exists). This is probably *not* what you're after, but it shows the sort of thing JavaScript can do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089650/fonts-fallbacks-how-to-specify-font-specific-rules/9089813#9089813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was answered just a minute ago by someone else (but already deleted?), you could use [Font Detector](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/) Javascript solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/FHnJw/1

Comment: It is really cool, I will use it if nobody finds a CSS way to achieve this (I know it is very unlikely, I already lost all hope someone will find the CSS way to do this)

Comment: It's very unlikely, indeed - it would require that CSS somehow would be able to detect the font used/installed - and as far as I know CSS is just for styling...

Comment: And could you please give me an upvote? I guess Fernando couldn't resist a downvote :-)

Comment: no prob, you're right about that. i just thought the -1 was a bit unfair, too :-)

Comment: I was going to post a different JS solution, that does essentially the same thing.  This is what you're looking for, OP.  I haven't found a CSS-only solution to this issue.  You can, however, use the JS test to create classes on say, your HTML or BODY tags, then you can do all your styling decisions in your CSS by referencing those classes.

Answer (score 2):

This might take some work to implement (I have not ever actually done it myself), but it seems that the `font-size-adjust` property helps "equalize" font's by standardizing the x-height. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-size-adjust for the official description.

Answer (score 0):

Font-size adjust only works with Firefox

The standalone 'font' css declaration only allows you to state font-size, style and weight once before declaring the different font families in succession so that's a no-go either

I'm sorry to say this cannot be done through css alone

As for the JS alternative, here's the one I recommend:

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Good luck