# fonts fallbacks: how to specify "font-specific" rules?

Tags: html, css, cross-platform

sometimes web-fonts don't load (for instance if hosted on google fonts)
and fallbacks may need special treatment, because they can be consistently different from other specified fonts

for instance:

```
font-family:'webfontname', 'winfont', 'linuxfont', sans-serif;
```

now the webfont should have

```
letter-spacing:2px;
```

but winfont should have

```
letter-spacing:-4px;
```

how can I manage this?

thank you

Comment: "sometimes web fonts doesn't load" - wat?

Comment: my English is random(), forget about it. corrected

Comment: Your English was fine, it's just that if you're embedding the font correctly, it should always load. Under what circumstances do fonts not load properly from Google Web Fonts?

Comment: the question is about styling fallbacks, independently by if they are or they are not web-fonts. google never goes down, but connections sometimes suck in my country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [Google Web Fonts](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/), so I suggest using the [WebFont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader), which will allow you to, for example, apply different CSS depending on whether the font is loading or loaded.

Here's a minimal example based on the code from my second link:

http://jsbin.com/izadif/ (spam refresh to see it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Cantarell' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .wf-loading h1 {
        font-family: serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: red;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
      }
      .wf-active h1 {
        font-family: 'Cantarell', serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is using Cantarell</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, you do need JavaScript to solve this. CSS alone can't adjust the `letter-spacing` depending on which font is being used.

Comment: sounds really painful. I hope in future there will be another way to set specific adjustment inside the @font-face rule. thank you for the answer, voted up for now!